# Running arbitrary vim commands from bash command line to script vim

Tags: vim

I want to script vim to edit files from the command line. For example I want to do something along the lines of:

```
vim -<SOME_OPTION> 'Iworld<Esc>bIhello <Esc>:wq helloworld.txt<CR>'
```

or:

```
echo 'Iworld<Esc>bIhello <Esc>:wq helloworld.txt<CR>' | vim
```

and have it save the file `helloworld.txt` with a body of `hello world`

Is this possible? I've tried a few different approaches but none seem to do it. I realize I can do things like `vim +PluginInstall` to run Ex commands from the command line, but I'd love to be able to string together arbitrary motions

Comment: Possible duplicate (in another section of StackExchange): http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34983/run-a-vim-macro-from-inside-a-bash-script

Comment: That's pretty close to what I want but not quite. If there's an ex command that lets me run arbitrary key presses like I can with mappings then that would definitely do the job

Comment: Doesn't `set -o vi` do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with the `+` flag and the `:normal` command:

```
$ vim +"norm Iworld" +"norm Ihello " +"wq helloworld.txt"
```

Comment: Nice, not quite as elegant as I was hoping for but that gets the job done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is vim's `-w/W` and `-s {scriptin}` option. Well in your case you should make a scriptfile, and with `-s file` to let vim execute all your "key presses"

I think vimgolf has used these options too.

Comment: Cool I'll peruse vimgolf for some examples

Comment: @JoshBodah you don't need the tmp file if you do `vim -s <(echo "whatever")`